# Compilation Error in a very silly program

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class KekOrCringe {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userGuess = "";
        boolean Continue = true;
        boolean ProperResponse = true;
        boolean IsCorrect = true;
        boolean YesNo = true;

            while (Continue)
            {
                int secretAnswer = (int)(Math.random() * 2 + 1);
                kekOrCringe(secretAnswer);
                while (!IsCorrect)
                {
                    System.out.println("Kek or Cringe?");
                    ProperResponse = false;
                    while (!ProperResponse) {
                        userGuess = scan.nextLine();
                        if (userGuess != "Kek") 
                            System.out.println("Your entry is invalid, please try again!");
                        else if (userGuess != "Cringe")
                            System.out.println("Your entry is invalid, please try again!");
                        else 
                            ProperResponse = true;
                    }
                    for (int guessCount = 0; guessCount < 1; guessCount++) {
                        if (userGuess = "Cringe" && userGuess != secretAnswer) {
                            System.out.println("It's KeK!"); 
                            guessCount++; }
                        else if (userGuess = "Kek" && userGuess != secretAnswer) { 
                            System.out.println("It's CrInGe!"); 
                            guessCount++; }
                        else
                            System.out.println("Mr. Morgan, you got it right my boy!");
                            IsCorrect = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                YesNo = false;
                while(!YesNo) {
                    System.out.println("Would you like to play again? Yes/No");
                    String answer = scan.nextLine();
                    if (answer.equals("No")) {
                        Continue = false;
                        YesNo = true;
                        System.out.println("Fine. You were Cringe anyway!");
                    }
                    else if (answer.equals("Yes")) {
                        YesNo = true;
                        Continue = true;
                        IsCorrect = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        

                            
    public static String kekOrCringe(int secretAnswer) {
        if (secretAnswer = 1) { return "Kek";}
        if (secretAnswer = 2) { return "Cringe";}
    }
}
```

Probably an overly complex way to do something unnecessary, but this is my first year in college learning to code, and I was asked to give this a try. I think it's funny, and will probably be funnier if it work, along with being good practice. I'm having trouble converting the int secretAnswer to a returned string, and then comparing the userGuess to the return type. Getting compilation errors on line 32 and 35. Any tips would be appreciated.

P.S. I realize it's silly. Trying to use this silly code as a learning opportunity.

Comment: What's the compilation error?

Comment: Incompatible operand types, String and int. Line 32.

The goal was to call the KekorCringe method using the value of secretAnswer, and then when KekorCringe gave the return type, it would redeclare the value of secretAnswer. It just didn't work out that way. Not sure how to change it.

Comment: There are multiple issues with the code. What you are trying to do here?

Comment: It's just an RNG program that generates two possibles answers. "Kek" or "Cringe."

The user has one guess to get it right.

Comment: Even if you resolve two compilation issues, there are couple of logical issues with the code. I would suggest you to please go though your code line by line using debugger. And understand what's going on.

Comment: Can I just express my delight that nobody is criticizing the contents of the code, but instead genuinely wants to help? It's very enlightening. I've only been at this in college for 6 weeks now, and writing my own things still presents challenges.

Comment: Also @notescrew, what were some of the logic errors you noticed? My compiler isn't giving me any other issues to correct, but it's still not working after some adjustments.

Comment: @Pat6578 These are not compilation error, these are logical errors. That's why I am asking what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: It's just an RNG program that generates two possibles answers. "Kek" or "Cringe." The user has one guess to get it right.

Answer (score 1):

Im guessing line 32 and 35 are the two ifs. userGuess != secretAnswer doesn't work since one is a String, the other an Integer. Your static method kekOrCringe(secretAnswer); returns the String you want, you just need to save it in a variable and then compare it to the userGuess.

Also please use lowercase variable names.

Comment: Even for boolean values?

Comment: Yes every variable should be named in lower camel case. Constants declared with static final should be in all uppercase: https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/JavaAndDS/JavaStyle.html#Naming

Answer (score 1):

I can't add a comment so I am writing here.

userGuess is String but secretAnswer is int, and you are trying to check if they are equal (`userGuess != secretAnswer`).

You can use a new variable like `secretGuess`, assign `kekOrCringe(secretAnswer)` to `secretGuess` and check if `userGuess` is equal to `secretGuess`.

Like this:

```
String secretGuess = kekOrCringe(secretAnswer);
if (userGuess != secretGuess) {
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compare int to string which is wrong

```
userGuess != secretAnswer
```

Also, instead of comparing you are assigning values inside if condition.

```
    if (secretAnswer = 1) { return "Kek";}
    if (secretAnswer = 2) { return "Cringe";}
```

It should be:

```
    if (secretAnswer == 1) { return "Kek";}
    if (secretAnswer == 2) { return "Cringe";}
```